Why we have inconsistent warning on missing await inside a method body
I was looking for a nasty bug after code refactoring (thank goodness our QA found a specific combination of circumstances to expose it) and figured out an await was missing.
During investigation I suspected something like that in an early stage and run code inspection with Rider. I also checked for warnings to not have

warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

However, to my surpise, it was actually the case.
So, I started digging and figured out that when you call a method that returns a Task without async from a method that returns a task without async, you don't have the warning.
Our code style is to avoid adding async/await when you only have 1 async call and pass through the results of the call further, hence, we had the problem.
The test app I used is to highlight the issue. I understand we should have passed the result further up the chain, but this is why it is called "a bug". Plus, from my point of view, the calls should be treated the same.
We use .NET Core 7.
namespace ConsoleAppAsyncAwait
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        }
    }

    public class AsyncTest
    {
        public Task CallerMethod1()
        {
            AwaitInside();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task CallerMethod2()
        {
            AsyncWithoutAwait();
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private Task AsyncWithoutAwait() => Delay(500);

        private async Task AwaitInside() => await Delay(1000);

        private async Task Delay(int milliseconds) => await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
    }
}
```

The build output:
> Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleAppAsyncAwait, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Projects\RandD\ConsoleAppAsyncAwait\Program.cs(15,13,15,26): warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
1>ConsoleAppAsyncAwait -> C:\Projects\RandD\ConsoleAppAsyncAwait\bin\Debug\net7.0\ConsoleAppAsyncAwait.dll
1>Done building project "ConsoleAppAsyncAwait.csproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:00.477 ==========

As you can see, there is only one warning in the result. And the second call - from CallerMethod2 - goes without the warning. Rider's Inspect Code also does not pick the case - but picks the first one.

Why it behaves like this? And - more importantly - how to find such places in the code?

@BrendanLynn The OP seems to know that and is asking how to find places in code where that happens.

To whoever closed the question: Thanks for quick finding of the duplicate! I definitely need to improve my search skills!
